# Charts are not connected in Link analysis in SAP Cloud Analytics

Tags: business-objects, sap-analytics-cloud

I am trying to do a link analysis between 2 charts in SAP Cloud Analytics but it's not working as expected, the charts should interact when I click on each of the charts, but it's not interacting.

I have used function below and followed this link - https://blogs.sap.com/2020/02/27/sac-analytic-application-reusable-script-function-for-linked-analysis/

```
{
    var currentSelection = arg1.getSelections();
       if(currentSelection.length > 0)
        {
          var selMembers = ArrayUtils.create(Type.string);
            for ( var i=0; i < currentSelection.length; i++ ) 
              {
                for(var currentDim in currentSelection[i])
                  {
                    if (currentDim = dim)
                      {
                        selMembers[i] =  currentSelection[i][currentDim];
                      }
                  }
              }
         arg2.getDataSource().setDimensionFilter (currentDim, selMembers);
        }
}
```

Comment: Do the charts use the same model?